# Package collection of modules as Erlang application?

Tags: module, erlang, package, synchronous

I have been working on some relatively simple Erlang modules. I have 4 modules that all work together. All the module names are "namespaced" like this:

```
project
project_helper
project_another_module
project_third_submodule
```

The modules are simple. They only contain functions. There is nothing concurrent. No processes, supervisors, or gen_servers. Just functions. To use the code you simple invoke functions in the top level `project` module. All calls are synchronous. You pass in data, wait for the function to finish, then you get data back.

My question is, how do I package this code up? Does it need to be setup as an application? And what benefits does an Erlang application provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how you are planning to use your code.
You do not have to set up your code as an application.
The simple way to package it is to compile all the modules via Erlang shell using command c(Module), then compress the folder and ship it when ever you need to.

However, I would suggest to follow best practice for OTP Applications:
http://learnyousomeerlang.com/building-otp-applications

If you setup your code as an OTP application, it would give you re-usability.
You can include those modules in another applications you create later.

I would suggest using rebar (https://github.com/rebar/rebar/wiki) as a build tool.
And put your code into some source control environment so you can include your code in your future projects easier.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pack this as application, so other applications could put your library as a dependency in their .app file.
This information used during release generation process to include your library.

To do this omit `{mod, ...}` section in your `your_library.app`.

from app manual: (`erl -man app`)

```
mod:
  Specifies the application callback module and a start argument, see application(3).

  The  mod  key is necessary for an application implemented as a supervision tree, or the application controller will not know how to start it. The mod key can be
  omitted for applications without processes, typically code libraries such as the application STDLIB.
```

Answer (score 0):

When a group of modules need to be packaged they still belong in an application. The application simply doesn't need a callback module. Learn You Some Erlang calls these types of applications "Library Applications". The libraries `.app` file should like a normal `.app` file. The only difference is that the mod tuple (`{mod, {Module, Args}}`) is not present.

Refer to LYSE for more details: http://learnyousomeerlang.com/building-otp-applications#library-applications